# Code to Autofill "INDEX" Array Formula and Readjust for New Unique Value in Lookup Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a Macro to take a list of products one department needs(they send a new one every day), and reference it against a report of every location of every item in the warehouse. So far, I have it set to count the amount of times the Product ID occurs in the location list (x) and copy that over to a new sheet x many times. Now I need it to get the sizes of the product and populate another column so that I can index Product ID & Size and find the location. That sheet will be printed and given to people to pull the product without them having to look in the system and find the locations of everything on the list (which currently takes about an hour.)

The problem, now, is I cannot get a formula to autofill without breaking at the first instance of a second unique value. I have found a workaround, but I have no idea how I would begin to go about automating it in vba.

*Array Formula in D2 =*

```
{=INDEX(Report!D:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D:G=$A2,ROW(Report!D:G)),ROW(A1)),4)}
```

*When it gets down to the second unique value in Column A, it breaks and it reads as*

```
{=INDEX(Report!D:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D:G=$A7,ROW(Report!D:G)),ROW(A6)),4)}
```

*But by changing the last ROW function back to A1, it works, like so:*

```
{=INDEX(Report!D:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D:G=$A7,ROW(Report!D:G)),ROW(A1)),4)}
```

[Formula breaks in first instance of 2nd unique value in Column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwinY.png)

[image]

[Formula works in first instance of 2nd unique value in Column A by changing final ROW function back to "A1" and dragging down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoqgO.png)

[image]

I tried adding an IFERROR to the formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Report!D:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D:G=$A2,ROW(Report!D:G)),ROW(A1)),4),INDEX(Report!D:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D:G=$A2,ROW(Report!D:G)),ROW($A$1)),4))}
```

But obviously that didn't work. It was more in desperation.

Is there a way to automate the process in VBA by having it detect a change in Column A and ONLY reverting the last ROW function in the formula to A1?

Or, is there a Formula that would work by autofilling?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
=INDEX(Report!G:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D:D=$A2,ROW(Report!D:D)),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

***NOTE:***  I have left your full column references in, this is poor practice when using array formulas, as they will iterate through every cell regardless if it has a value or not.  This will do over a million calculations PER formula.  This will slow down your calc times and may even crash excel.

It is recommended that you refer to only those cells that have data in them.

One way to deal with the data is to make the references inside the small variable.  We can do that with an INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Report!G:G,SMALL(IF(Report!D$1:INDEX(Report!D:D,MATCH(1E+99,Report!D:D))=$A2,ROW(Report!D$1:INDEX(Report!D:D,MATCH(1E+99,Report!D:D)))),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)))
```

Now the formula will automatically set the end of the reference to that last cell with a number in column D of the Report sheet, and no extra non essential loops will be made.

Comment: It works! Oh man, Thanks! 2 questions about your answer if you don't mind...

How would I change your formula to not have full column references?

and 

Why did yours work? What is it doing with the COUNTIF?

EDIT: Nevermind the first question. I got it.

Comment: The first question, I answered see edit, the second:  The second reference in the countif is relative so as the formula is dragged down it increases the range from the top to only the row in which the formula is found, so it is counting duplicates so each change in A will start the counter back to 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything works perfectly. And nevermind my comment edit, your edit was better than my solution.